# Swift 3 put 2 colors in the same UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

I want to achieve this effect on UIViews and UIImageViews:

[image: UIImageView]

[image: UIView]

On UIView I know I can put 2 inside of it with different colors, but I pretty much think there must be a better way and I don't know how to do it in the UIImageVIew. Some sort of pod would be really useful because I couldn't find one.

Comment: You should use image with two colors. It is more relevant than trying to put two colors in image view. Why do you want to put two colors ? Use images instead!

Comment: Asking for a tutorial or a library is not a valid topic here.

Comment: the thing is I need to make it grey when it's "not active", and I can't apply normal tint on it cuz the grey would be in 2 colors

Comment: @ElTomato code would be totally fine here, I just said I would prefer a pod since it makes things easier. If you have a valid method I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could add a gradient layer where instead of making a transition from one color to another you would go from a color to the same color until the middle point, and the same with the second half. Check the example:

```
let twoColorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100))
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = twoColorView.bounds
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
gradientLayer.locations = [NSNumber(value: 0.0), NSNumber(value: 0.5), NSNumber(value: 0.5), NSNumber(value: 1.0)]
twoColorView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

and of course you can style that view further, such as:

```
twoColorView.layer.cornerRadius = twoColorView.bounds.height / 2
twoColorView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

It results in this:

[image]

**EDIT**:

It can be generalized to accept any number of colors. Create a `UIView` extension and add your logic there. In this way the colors can be applied to any `UIView` and its subclasses, such as UILabel, UIButton, UIImageView, etc.

```
extension UIView {
    func addColors(colors: [UIColor]) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds

        var colorsArray: [CGColor] = []
        var locationsArray: [NSNumber] = []
        for (index, color) in colors.enumerated() {
            // append same color twice
            colorsArray.append(color.cgColor)
            colorsArray.append(color.cgColor)
            locationsArray.append(NSNumber(value: (1.0 / Double(colors.count)) * Double(index)))
            locationsArray.append(NSNumber(value: (1.0 / Double(colors.count)) * Double(index + 1)))
        }

        gradientLayer.colors = colorsArray
        gradientLayer.locations = locationsArray

        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

        // This can be done outside of this funciton
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height / 2
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

And adding colors:

```
    let colorView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100))
    colorView.addColors(colors: [.red, .green, .blue])
    view.addSubview(colorView)
```

This is the result:

[image]

Be careful not to call this function multiple times in the lifecycle of the view, because it will add sublayers on top of each other. So either call it once or remove the sublayers before you call `addColors` again. So of course there is room for improvement.

Comment: If you specify your problem perhaps someone might help you.

Comment: `UITableViewCell` depends a lot on how `UITableView` displays it - you need to account for cell reuse, timing (e.g. try setting in `willDisplayCell`) and cell's subviews(`contentView`). But without further info I cannot tell what goes wrong for you.

Answer (score 2):

a more static and objective way in Swift 4,

```
class ColouredView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass : AnyClass {
        return ColouredLayer.self
    }
}


class ColouredLayer: CAGradientLayer{

    override init() {
        super.init()

        let colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue]
        addColors(colors)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}


extension CAGradientLayer{

    func addColors(_ colors: [UIColor]){
        var colorsArray: [CGColor] = []
        var locationsArray: [NSNumber] = []
        for (index, color) in colors.enumerated() {
            // append same color twice
            colorsArray.append(color.cgColor)
            colorsArray.append(color.cgColor)
            locationsArray.append(NSNumber(value: (1.0 / Double(colors.count)) * Double(index)))
            locationsArray.append(NSNumber(value: (1.0 / Double(colors.count)) * Double(index + 1)))
        }

        self.colors = colorsArray
        locations = locationsArray
    }
}
```

just set and assign the `ColouredView`

Thanks to @Au Ris's answer

Answer (score 2):

Improvement to above answer with direction

```
extension UIView {

enum GradientDirection {
    case horizontal
    case vertical
}

func fillColors(_ colors: [UIColor], withPercentage percentages: [Double], direction: GradientDirection = .horizontal) {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    var colorsArray: [CGColor] = []
    var locationsArray: [NSNumber] = []
    var total = 0.0
    locationsArray.append(0.0)
    for (index, color) in colors.enumerated() {
        // append same color twice
        colorsArray.append(color.cgColor)
        colorsArray.append(color.cgColor)
        // Calculating locations w.r.t Percentage of each
        if index + 1 < percentages.count {
            total += percentages[index]
            let location = NSNumber(value: total / 100)
            locationsArray.append(location)
            locationsArray.append(location)
        }
    }
    locationsArray.append(1.0)
    if direction == .horizontal {
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    } else {
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    }
    gradientLayer.colors = colorsArray
    gradientLayer.locations = locationsArray
    backgroundColor = .clear
    layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be generalized more to accept any number of colors, with their respective percentage

```
extension UIView {
    func addColors(colors: [UIColor], withPercentage percentages: [Double]) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        var colorsArray: [CGColor] = []
        var locationsArray: [NSNumber] = []
        var total = 0.0
        locationsArray.append(0.0)
        for (index, color) in colors.enumerated() {
            // append same color twice
            colorsArray.append(color.cgColor)
            colorsArray.append(color.cgColor)
            // Calculating locations w.r.t Percentage of each
            if index+1 < percentages.count{
                total += percentages[index]
                let location: NSNumber = NSNumber(value: total/100)
                locationsArray.append(location)
                locationsArray.append(location)
            }
        }
        locationsArray.append(1.0)
        gradientLayer.colors = colorsArray
        gradientLayer.locations = locationsArray
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let colors: [UIColor] = [.red, .green, .blue, .yellow, .purple]
let percentages: [Double] = [10, 30, 20, 5, 35]
testView.addColors(colors: colors, withPercentage: percentages)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Thanks to @Au Ris's answer

Comment: Hii i have a quick question. can i add animation when color fill ?
It animate and fill the color to UIView. Thank You!